How to setup Lightsail kubernetes load balancer
I'm following this article How to run kubernetes on Amazon Lightsail, so far so good. I'm able to setup the kubernetes cluster. I'm stuck on setting up the load balancer. I have two front-end facing applications. Web application and image server. Image server is nginx server in kubernetes cluster along with web application (spring boot/tomcat).
In my laptop, I set up the ingress nginx controller which is sending the traffic to these different services based on the matching url regex. Should I configure the ingress nginx controller in lightsail as well or there is another way to do in LightSail?. I'm setting this the first time, not sure how to proceed. I also don't know to connect lightsail loadbalancer to ingress controller. I will appreciate any guidance in this regard.
